# Datamapper ORM for Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, datamapper, codeigniter-datamapper

I've been searching for ORM that can be integrate for PHP Codeigniter. I landed with [DataMapper](http://datamapper.maglok.nl/pages/download.html). But unfortunately the source code/library is not available anymore. Is it possible that it's not been used now or development for this was stopped? With more searching, I found topics on DataMapper but it was dated between 2011-2012 and it was the highly recommended ORM for CI in those times. I can't seem to find topics that DataMapper was stopped.

Question is if DataMapper is still available at this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataMapper is still available, here is the [source](https://github.com/saekort/datamapper) but it not currently maintained by the [original developer](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/). To be frank the new version also doesn't seem quite active.

Comment: In case you need an alternative, here are some
 
 1. [GasORM](http://gasorm-doc.taufanaditya.com/)  
 2. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) - Probably the best to work with large data models but have to do some work to integrate with codeigniter
 3. [Propel](http://propelorm.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Will be difficult to answer if it is still available at this time, but there is an alternative ORM tool called Doctrine. [link](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel's Eloquent standalone. :)

Comment: it's an old thread, but Eloquent follows the ActiveRecord pattern, not DataMapper.